# setting Flex Panel title and status colors dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am updating an older project, written in Flex 3 with some new functionality and I cant figure out how to do something that appears to be really simple.

I am passing in data to a panel via XML and binding the properties of the panel to this XML, so for example:

```
<mx:Panel label="{_data.@label}" title="{_data.@title}" borderColor="{_data.@borderColor}"/>
```

My question is simple:

How do I set the panel Title and Status colors using data that is passed in the XML?

You can set titleStyleName to the name of a styledeclaration but the are no styles for titleColor or statusColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jax, however that wasnt quite the answer I was looking for.

The difference between say for example, color and titleStylename  is that you can directly bind the css attribute of color to your XML data for example

'color={_data.@color}'

However this does not wok with titleStyleName because it requires setting up a new styledecclaration.

I have come up wiith a solution however, where I have extended the Panel and added a Bindable titleColor variable.  I then set the color of the textbox upon any changes - see below:

'
public class PanelWithColorTitle extends Panel 
    {

```
    public function PanelWithColorTitle() 
    {

    }

    [Bindable] public var _titleColor:uint

    public function setTitleAndStatusColor():void
    {
        trace(">>PanelWithColorTitle:setTitleAndStatusColor--")
        titleTextField.setColor(_titleColor)
        statusTextField.setColor(_titleColor)

    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void 
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        setTitleAndStatusColor()
    }
}
```

}
'

Thanks for looking anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You use [statusStyleName and titleStyleName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Panel.html) to specify the css style name which you can then specify the color.